# Getting incorrect result when using floor() while calculating compount interest

Tags: python, python-3.x, floor

In my code, I use the well-known formula for calculating compound interest. I used `floor()` for every element in the result, but I got an unexpected result, i.e.
for 6 months I got `[1300, 1690, 2197, 2856, 3712, 4826]` where the last number should be 4825, if calculating manually every time skipping decimals (what `floor()` actually should do in my loop but it doesn't for the last number).

The question is why? How overcome this "error"?

Here is my code:

```
from math import floor

def get_plan(current_production: int, month: int, percent: int):

    monthly_production = []
    for i in range(1, month + 1):
        #calculating percentage using compound interest formula
        monthly_production.append(floor(current_production * (1 + percent / 100) ** i))
    return monthly_production 

get_plan(1000, 6, 30)
```

Comment: Can you explain why 4825 should be the correct result and not 4826?

Comment: Substituting the given values, I get `1000 * (1 + 30 / 100) ** 6` which is `4826.809000000001`, which is correctly floored to `4826`. I suppose the issue is that your *intermediate* results *aren't* floored; you'd need a "floorpow" at which point you should just use the last montly production in your current formula, making it recursive.

Comment: @mkrieger1 You can check it with your calculator if you will throw out decimals from every result in the row.

Comment: The last iteration is `1000 * (1 + 30 / 100) ** 6` which is `4826.809`. I don't understand why you expect `floor(4826.809)` to become `4825`.

Comment: @DeepSpace because penultimate  3712 + 30%  = 4825,6

Comment: @avkpol That is not how `1000 * (1 + 30 / 100) ** 6` is evaluated, regardless if using Python or not. `30 / 100` -> `0.3` ;  `1 + 0.3` -> `1.3` ; `1.3 ** 6` -> `4.826809` ; `1000 * 4.826809` -> `4826.809`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting the given values you get `1000 * (1 + 30 / 100) ** 6` which is `4826.809000000001` in floats and correctly floored to 4826. I suppose the issue is that your intermediate results aren't floored: When you calculate it manually, you say you "throw away the decimals from every result" (after every step).

To fix this in your Python code, simply don't use float exponentiation which doesn't floor after every multiplication but instead multiply with the interest in each step:

```py
from math import floor

def get_plan(current_production: int, month: int, percent: int):
    monthly_production = []
    for i in range(1, month + 1):
        #calculating percentage using compound interest formula
        current_production = floor(current_production * (1 + percent / 100))
        monthly_production.append(current_production)
    return monthly_production
```

`get_plan(1000, 6, 30)` correctly yields `[1300, 1690, 2197, 2856, 3712, 4825]` then.

Comment: So the actual issue was with OP's implementation in that they never used the value of the previous iteration.

Comment: @DeepSpace can you please explain?